How to build the logic of OTP using JMeter?
I have to record the jmeter script for mobile application. I have setup the proxy and api's are recorded in jmeter. But facing issues during the login into application, i want to perform the load testing with 50000 users, so each has there dummy email id. But when user entered the login credentials(i.e email id) then OTP sent to there email id.
So how can I send the OTP on there dummy email id and how to fetch that OTP from email through Jmeter script.
I want a logic to build script for above situation.

If the OTP is sent to the email address it has to be the real one, i.e. you will need to

Create 50000 email addresses beforehand
Set up 50000 credentials and put them into a CSV file. Configure CSV Data Set Config to read the credentials from the CSV file.
Perform login and get the OTP using Mail Reader Sampler
Additionally you can write the OTPs into another CSV file using Flexible File Writer

In order to exclude these actions from the real test (unless you're trying to test OTP generation performance) you can put the above steps somewhere in setUp Thread Group
